# Include does not work as expected on EF Core 3.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.0

I migrated a ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC web application to .NET Core 3.0. In some cases the include does not work propperly.

```
var forms = _context.CheckInOutForm
    .Include(x => x.Employee)
    .AsQueryable();

// apply filter and sorting
forms = FilterForms(forms);
forms = SortForms(forms, sort);

// convert to viewmodel (database model as parameter in the constructer)
var items = forms.Select(x => new CheckInOutViewModel(x));

// load data for current page (with X.PagedList nuget package)
var pagedList = items.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
```

For some reason EF builds a query for the table CheckInOutForm with an inner join to Employee but only select fields from the table CheckInOutForm. I catched the generated query with the SQL profiler and analyzed it.

This code worked fine before the migration. I've read that EF Core 3.0 changed the behaviour of joining tables. I still don't understand why it creates a select with the fields of only one table.

The items.ToPagedList creates a select with OFFSET and FETCH NEXT. The same library works on other pages within the same application.

Any hints or ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Include` never worked with `.Select`.  But you might have been getting partial client-side execution in EF Core 2, where your `.Include` runs server-side, and your `.Select` runs client-side.

With EF Core 3, you always get server-side query execution, so your `.Select` will suppress the `.Include`.

So (assuming `FilterForms` and `SortForms` don't do anything strange to the query) you just need to run the query upstream of the projection into the ViewModel.  EG

```
var items = forms.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize).Select(x => new CheckInOutViewModel(x));
```

Comment: Thanks David, this did the trick. Since I have only a few 100k records I didn't realize the query was on the client side executed. I like the changes in EF3.0 - it makes applications more stable and increaces the performance. One has to be careful though on migrating old applications.